# Refactor nested Observable + Promise + Observable

Tags: angular, nested, observable

I usually end up with nested structures while working asynchronously. When the subscriptions gives me the responses, then I do something, when the promise gives me the response, then I do something and so on. An example is this:

```
  loadHacks(hackService, hacksStorageService) {
    firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(
      (user) => {
        if (user) {
          const uid = user.uid;
          const hacks = hackService.getHacks();
          if (hacks.length === 0) {
            user.getIdToken()
              .then(
                token => {
                  hacksStorageService.fetchHacks(token, uid)
                    .subscribe(
                      (hacks: Hack[]) => {
                        hackService.setHacks(hacks);
                      }
                    )
                }
              )
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

onIdTokenChanged places an Observer to the token, getIdToken is a Promise, fetchHacks is an Observable.

How could I refactor the code? I have read about the do, but I don't really grasp it. If someone could tell me how to refactor such nested codes, I would be very grateful

Comment: Just use `flatMap`.

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293